# What to use for multi-class probability label data and same type prediction in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data labelled with probability values for 4 different classes and I also want to predict in this manner. However I could not find any algorithm handling such data and predicting probability values to each class instead of binariez order. What can I use in such a problem?

Comment: There's no estimator in scikit-learn that takes probability distributions as `y`. If you train on the `argmax` of the prob dists, then logistic regression, naive Bayes and some of the tree ensemble estimators should work.

Comment: @larsmans won't we lose information when we are training on the "argmax"?

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: yes, some information is lost. The alternative, which I only think of just now, is to feed a sample with probability `p` to the training algorithm twice: once with label 1 and a `sample_weight` of `p`, once with label 0 and a `sample_weight` of `1-p`. In the multiclass case, this can get complicated, though.

Answer (score 4):

scikit-learn classifiers do not support training on probability distributions out of the box. The workaround is to feed the samples *K* times to the training algorithm for *K* classes, using the probability distribution as a `sample_weight`. Not all classifiers support that, but `SGDClassifier` does and will fit a logistic regression model with the right settings.

For the sake of example, let's make a random training set.

```
>>> X = np.random.randn(10, 6)
>>> p_pos = np.random.random_sample(10)
>>> p_pos
array([ 0.19751302,  0.01538067,  0.87723187,  0.63745719,  0.38188726,
        0.62435933,  0.3706495 ,  0.12011895,  0.61787941,  0.82476533])
```

Now feed this to a logistic regression model trained with SGD, **twice**.

```
>>> lr = SGDClassifier(loss="log")
>>> y = p_pos > .5
>>> lr.fit(np.vstack([X, X]), np.hstack([np.ones(10), np.zeros(10)]),
...        sample_weight=np.hstack([p_pos, 1 - p_pos]))
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal',
       loss='log', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5,
       random_state=None, shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

The previous example was for binary LR. Multiclass LR is a little more complicated. Let's say you have a matrix P of `n_samples` probability distributions, each a row vector:

```
>>> P = np.abs(np.random.randn(10, 4))
>>> P /= P.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)  # normalize
>>> P
array([[ 0.22411769,  0.06275884,  0.25062665,  0.46249682],
       [ 0.20659542,  0.06153031,  0.03973449,  0.69213978],
       [ 0.20214651,  0.084988  ,  0.12751119,  0.5853543 ],
       [ 0.35839192,  0.30211805,  0.01093208,  0.32855796],
       [ 0.34267131,  0.07151225,  0.09413323,  0.4916832 ],
       [ 0.26670351,  0.30988833,  0.22118608,  0.20222208],
       [ 0.00694437,  0.68845955,  0.18413326,  0.12046281],
       [ 0.34344352,  0.27397581,  0.34626692,  0.03631376],
       [ 0.29315434,  0.25683875,  0.14935136,  0.30065555],
       [ 0.19147437,  0.22572122,  0.57924412,  0.00356029]])
```

Now we have four classes, so we need to feed the training set to the estimator four times.

```
>>> n_classes = P.shape[1]
>>> X4 = np.vstack([X for i in xrange(n_classes)])
>>> y = np.arange(n_classes).repeat(10)
>>> sample_weight = P.T.ravel()
>>> lr.fit(X4, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal',
       loss='log', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', power_t=0.5,
       random_state=None, shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```